# How to create a Backbone Collection with data that is not flat

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am not sure how to create a Backbone Collection using the following data, and wonder how it should be approached.

The `items` property in the JSON makes sense to me to use as a collection since it is an array already.  But is there a good way of getting the other information available to the collection, or keeping it persistent in case it needs to be referenced in a view?  How should I handle the following data format for a collection?

Here's some example data and code:

```
{
"page": 1,
"total": 1000,
"items": [
    {
        "title": "title of item 1",
        "color": "green",
        "type": [
            {
                "isStandard": "Yes",
                "size": "Large"
            },
            {
                "isStandard": "No",
                "size": "Medium"
            }
        ],
        "price": "9.99"
    },
    {
        "title": "title of item 2",
        "color": "blue",
        "type": [
            {
                "isStandard": "No",
                "size": "XXL"
            },
            {
                "isStandard": "No",
                "size": "XXS"
            }
        ],
        "price": "19.99"
    },
    {
        "title": "title of item 3",
        "color": "red",
        "type": [
            {
                "isStandard": "No",
                "size": "Small"
            },
            {
                "isStandard": "Yes",
                "size": "Large"
            }
        ],
        "price": "229.99"
    }
],
"date": "Wed Oct 08 2014 21:04:05 GMT-0500 (CDT)"
}
```

```js
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var SomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: SomeModel,
  
  url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/backbonecollectiontest/collections/backbonecollection?apiKey=qcVNgNb-s1X4WJkLeRDfykxqtMG-ezkC',
  
  parse: function(response) {
      // Returning only the items data.  But this will be missing data in the response
      // that is not included in the items property
      return response[0].items;
  }
});

var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-container',
  
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new SomeCollection();
      
        this.collection.fetch();
      
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render); 
    },
  
    template: _.template( $('#some-template').html() ),
  
    render: function() {
      
      this.$el.html( this.template( {collection: this.collection.toJSON()} ) );
      
   }
});

var someView = new SomeView();
```

```html
<div class="js-container">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="some-template">
    <h3>How should I get the 'page', 'total', and 'date' properties in the data here?</h3>
    <% _.each(collection, function(element, index) { %>
      <p>
        <%- element.title %>, 
        <%- element.color %>, 
        <% _.each(element.type, function(ele, i) { %>
          <%- ele.isStandard %>,
          <%- ele.size %>,
        <% }); %>
        <%- element.price %>
      </p>
    <% }); %>

</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually asking for here, as you're using very vague language such as "getting the other information", "keeping it persistent" and "how should I handle...".  Phrasing your question in the form of a specific problem which needs a solution will help people to answer.  Otherwise, your code looks perfectly fine.  Does it run?

Comment: @TNguyen I apologize for the unclear question.  The code does run, but I am not sure how to create flat models and collections with data in the format I provided.  I wonder also if flat models are necessary and how others handle data like that.

Comment: Well the first thing I would say is that it's not really necessary to create flat models.  This is one of the main benefits of JSON, that it allows you to serialize more complex data objects simply.  It's extremely rare that I ever find the need for flat data models.  I think that mindset is an outdated leftover from old relational database design, where a row of data was always retrieved in a flat de-normalized format.

Comment: @TNguyen Thanks for the advice!  I have heard that data models should be flat and that led me to wondering how to deal with data in my example.  All the articles and tutorials I saw on backbone use pretty flat data so I wondered how others deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like u need nested model here:

Here is an prototype to catch the idea, for more info checkout [this post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/)

1) create model and collection for items

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "title": "no-title",
        "color": "no",
        "type": [],
        "price": "0"
    }
});

var ItemsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
});
```

2) create parent model, looks like page in your case:

```
var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        page: 0,
        date: 'now',
        total: 0,
        items: []
    },
    initialize: function() {
        var items = this.get('items');
        this.set('items', new ItemsCollection(items));
    }  
});
```

If you have an array in JSON resp, u can create PageCollection as well.

Comment: `this.items.set(new ItemsCollection(items));` doesn't produce the result you expected. `this.items` refers to Model's **property** `items`, not **attribute**. The right way would be: `this.set('items', new ItemsCollection(items))`. Although it is unclear where `items` variable comes from in your code?

Comment: @hindmost, thanks for your attention, i've undated the code, idea is to re-define `items` property with BB collection instance

Comment: @Evgeniy Thank you! Although I am still a little lost. Let me see if I follow.  The PageModel creates an ItemCollection when it is initialized.  Here is a fiddle I have been editting to try and log the information.  When I log results of PageModel I see an additional property which contains the feteched data.  Although I'm not sure where this additional property came from.  http://jsfiddle.net/ozt00tt2/

Comment: @Mdd, sorry for my mistake, piece of code in `initialize` should be inside `parse`. Also i've updated fiddle to clarify idea - http://jsfiddle.net/ozt00tt2/6/ . I've added collectionView for items and render it after page view render.

Comment: @Evgeniy Thank you so much for the great explanation.  I have been really interested in how other people approach data when it is not flat like in my example.